# How can I get rid of 'Unnamed 0' in Pandas csv file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export-to-csv, data-analysis

I have this excel sheet and I need to convert it to csv format [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cciEZ.png).
Im using pandas and function `df.to_csv()`, but there is an empty cell in my initial table, so I got this after all [CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYBCo.png)
Using `index_col = 0` is unreasonable, because I lose my first column with information.

Comment: Is the Time the column name of the first column? Why are you using Pandas?

Comment: `df.to_csv(index=False)` so you don't include the index in the CSV

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple solution?

```
df.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1, inplace=True)
```